# Instantiating a class in the constructor when the other class has instated the other class in the constructor

Tags: php, class, oop, constructor, instantiation

When I want to use a class's methods and properties in another class, I instantiate those classes in the constructor and set them as instance properties.

```
<?php
class ClassA
{
    private $classB;
    private $classC;

    public function __construct()
    {
        // Instantiate class B and C and set the instance properties
        $this->classB = new ClassB();
        $this->classC = new ClassC();
    }

    // Example
    public function getTest() 
    {
        if ($this->classB->isTest1()) {
            return 'some value';

        } elseif ($this->classC->isTest1()) {
            return 'some other value';

        } else {
            return 'some other value';
        }
    }
}

$ClassA = new ClassA();
$test = $ClassA->getTest();
```

There are some times where I want to instantiate a class in the constructor, and that other class has also instantiated the other class the constructor too:

```
    <?php

    class ClassA
    {
        private $classB;

        public function __construct()
        {
            // Instantiate class B and set classB instance propert.
            $this->classB = new ClassB();
        }
    }

    class ClassB
    {
        private $classA;

        public function __construct()
        {
            // Instantiate class A and set classA property so we can use class A methods and properties in this class.
            $this->classA = new ClassA();
        }
    }

    $ClassA = new ClassA();
    $ClassB = new ClassB();
```

This will fail though because Class A instantiates class B in the constructor, class B instantiates class A in the constructor, and it keeps doing this going back and fourth until I get the PHP error message, 'Allowed memory size of ##### bytes exhausted'.

What would be the best workaround for this? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Use dependency injection instead.

Comment: This looks like a bad design, you are building so many dependencies into the class structure that it's doomed to cause problems.

Comment: Aside from the use of [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection), as already mentioned by @tereško, one of your key problems here is that you have a [cyclic dependency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_dependency). Which means you cannot instantiate `A` without `B`, but you also cannot instantiate `B` without `A`, which means you can never instantiate either class.

Answer (score 1):

If your aim is to have a back-and-forth relation between two objects, then one of the many solutions is to provide the back-reference when you have it:

```
class ClassA {
    public $objB;

    public function __construct($other = null) {
        $this->objB = $other ? $other : new ClassB($this);
    }
}

class ClassB {
    public $objA;

    public function __construct($other = null) {
        $this->objA = $other ? $other : new ClassA($this);
    }
}

$objA = new ClassA();
var_dump($objA->objB->objA === $objA); // true
```

NB: I prefer to name the variables `$objA` instead of `$classA`, as they are not classes, but instances of classes.

NB2: I declared those variables as public members only to be able to demonstrate with `var_dump` that the references are working.